# Delphi (RAD Studio XE5) Mobile: need design-time form designer to maintain aspect ratio of top-aligned image

Tags: delphi, mobile, cross-platform, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have a simple login form that consists of a logo graphic aligned alTop, username and password text fields and a submit button. I am wondering how to setup the design-time settings so that when I change the form factor (design-time layout graphic), say from iphone to ipad or nexus tablet, my top-aligned graphic is resized or swapped to one with the correct dimensions based on the original aspect ratio of the image (should fill the entire top of the screen but be correctly proportioned).

I have tried various configurations of Alignment and WrapMode to no avail and dabbled with TScaledLayout too. Stretch is not what is desired. Whenever I switch design-time form factors, I need the graphic to show in the form designer so that it fills the screen space from side to side and has a height of the correct value based on the original aspect ratio.

I know how to code the correct dimensions or swap the images through event handlers at runtime. I am wondering if using FormFamily and/or MultiResBitmap is the answer but don't know how to connect everything for correct design-time display of the forms.